# Cannot create shortcuts on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

I have a strange issue. This is Windows 7 Enterprise 32-bit.

I want to create a shortcut in `C:\Program Files\Quest Software\SQL Navigator for Oracle` folder. When I right click in that folder and select `New > Shortcut`, nothing happens. I tried to do the same thing in `C:\Program Files\Quest Software\` and `C:\Program Files\`, even in `C:\` and nothing happens either. Finally I tried to do that on my desktop, and as I expected, nothing.

As a side note, I can create new folders in all of the above paths by right clicking and selecting `New > Folder`.

I have the local administrator rights on this machine. The machine is a work laptop on a company domain.

What could be the reason for that? How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that an over-zealous register-cleaner has destroyed the required registry entries.

See this article for restoring :
[How to Remove and Restore the Default Windows 7 New Context Menu Items](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/28677-new-context-menu-remove-restore-default-menu-items.html).

Comment: I applied **Step 9** (removed the registry entry for new shortcut and restored it), and it works. Thanks. (For those who suffer from the same problem, [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/90880d1281623225-new-context-menu-remove-restore-default-menu-items-shortcut_new_context_menu_item.zip) are the reg files.)